# why the Number of ret instructions is greater than number of call instructions?

Tags: c++, operating-system, cpu-architecture, intel-pin

i have written a pintool. it implements a stack for a program while instructions are executed. In case a call instruction is encountered it pushes the address of next instruction in sequence to stack. when the called procedure is completed and the return instruction is encountered it verifies the target address in ret instruction is equal to the top of stack and pop out the top.

normally the number of call instructions should be equal to return instructions. but this tool monitors a larger number of return instructions. how is this possible? what is the problem? how can i solve it?

edit 1:

code for pintool

```
VOID f_jump(int a, int b) 
{ 
s.push(b); 
cout<<s.top()<<"\t"; 
icount1++; 
}
VOID f_ret(int a, int b) 
{ 
if (b==s.top())
 { 
   cout<<s.top(); 
   s.pop(); 
   cout<<"\tOK"<<endl; 
 }
else 
cout<<"Exploit\t"<<endl<<s.top()<<"\t"<<b<<endl; 
icount2++; 
} 

VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v) 
{ 
if( INS_IsCall(ins) ) 
  { 
  INS_InsertCall(ins,IPOINT_TAKEN_BRANCH,AFUNPTR(f_jump),
  IARG_BRANCH_TARGET_ADDR,IARG_RETURN_IP, IARG_END); 
  } 
if( INS_IsRet(ins) )
  { 
 INS_InsertCall(ins,IPOINT_BEFORE,AFUNPTR(f_ret),
 IARG_INST_PTR,IARG_BRANCH_TARGET_ADDR, IARG_END);
  } 
}
```

i run it on various binaries and processes but the problem remained the same. please help.

Comment: A function can have only one entry point (the target of a call) but can have multiple exit points (the ret instructions).

Comment: Q: Have you tried generating assembly outout (e.g. `gcc -S`) and examining the assembly source?  Q: Would your tool "detect" multiple "RET" calls if the function happened to have multiple "return" exits?  We really need more info before we can speculate...

Comment: @paulsm4  i haven't t generated the assembly output, and what you mean by detecting multiple exits? isn't during execution only one of the return exit is taken?

Comment: Technically, a compiler can make do without `call`s by combining `push`s and `jmp`s. That might be good for performance in some cases. I don't know if your compiler is up for such hackery, though. Regarding your comment, I think the others were assuming you are talking about analyzing the assembly output, not the actual execution path.

Comment: Technically, a compiler can also use a `ret` instruction to generate a jump, e.g. as in `push <some address>, ret`. This can be handy if there's a need for a dynamic jump target but no free register available for a register-based jump. It's very rare, though.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, if you're talking about static code - true, but then again a function may be called from multiple places. If you're talking about dynamic code (and that's what the question seems to be about) - no, you can hit only one ret per function invocation.

Comment: @Prof, you're going to have to post some code: a short version of the pintool, and the program you ran it with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pintool: Number of call and ret mismatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45181624/pintool-number-of-call-and-ret-mismatch)

Comment: @paulsm4 that thread is closed

Comment: @Prof, please add the code in the question (you can edit it). By the way, in some cases you can have ret insts without a call when someone's doing tricks with far jumps, or trying to invoke ROP attacks, but i'm not sure how frequent that would be.

Comment: @Leeor done, have a look

Comment: Are you sure you're not counting `jmp` instructions as `call`?  I haven't used Pintool, but are you sure that asking for `IARG_RETURN_IP` as a 2nd argument restricts it to only giving you jumps that *have* a return-IP?  Or maybe it's counting tail-call `jmp` instructions, like when you `jmp func` instead of `call func` / `ret`?   Like in this example: https://godbolt.org/g/fv5y77

Comment: Do you see any "exploit" printed? after one case your reference stack may be corrupted and stop reporting matches, no?

Comment: @PeterCordes in that case don't you think the call count will be greater than the ret count ? and in the present scenario the program is reporting a larger number of returns.

Comment: Oops, I forgot which way you said your imbalance was!  Yes, my guess would explain the other way.  Does your program use a lot of exception handlers?  (Although again I think that would result in more calls than rets from unwinding the stack instead of returning up through the call chain.)

Comment: @Leeor yes Exploit is printed on every mismatch but the stack is not corrupted as we move forward like this 
c1, r1 ok
c2, c3, r3 ok r2 ok
c4, rExtra Exploit (and rExtra rejected)  r4 ok

Comment: @PeterCordes actually no i haven't implemented any exception handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have longjmp, C++ exceptions or exit calls in a function call, which makes you miss the return instructions of that function call.

This has been discussed many times [here](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/pinheads/conversations/topics/7383)

Comment: A `jmp` tailcall skips a `call` as well as a `ret`.  Also, the *dynamic* count of `call` / `ret` should normally match, shouldn't it?  (Or is this PIN tool doing a static instruction count?)   Multiple call-sites to one function vs. multiple return paths out of one function only affect the static instruction balance, not dynamic.

Comment: My experience is that the dynamic count of call/ret never matches and processing needs to be done to reconciliate these figures. PIN newsgroup (yahoogroup) is full of discussions on this issue. I don't know what you mean with a "jmp" tailcall skips a call as well as a ret. I update my example as the second part of your comment is true.

Comment: I thought your last paragraph was talking about a case like `int foo() { return bar(); }` where `foo` compiles to `jmp bar` instead of `call bar; ret`.  i.e. an optimized tail-call.  In that case, there's one fewer call and one fewer ret, so the balance isn't affected.  The `ret` in the function you tail-call still executes, and it doesn't un-balance the hardware return-address predictor stack.  (I guess if you're only instrumenting some functions, e.g. not libraries, then this could PIN count differences even if it's not a performance problem.)

Comment: It was not a good example. I removed it and added further references.